# Using XPath to grab the text of a specific tag

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to extract the value from a specific key, in my XML, through XPath.

---

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OMRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ApplicationId>User</ApplicationId>
    <BusinessProcessId>GiftCard</BusinessProcessId>
    <Data>
        <Item>
            <Key>fsf_addr</Key>
            <Value>Lancelot</Value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Key>email_addr</Key>
            <Value>TEST@TEST.COM</Value>
        </Item>
    </Data>
</OMRequest>
```

and I want to grab the `value` from the `key` that has `email_addr` via XPath, so I want an XPath that returns the value `TEST@TEST.COM`.

I have the following XPath, however, this will grab the first value:

`/OMRequest/Data/Item/Value/text()`.

I am wondering what XPath I can use in order to get that specific value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath should do

`/OMRequest/Data/Item[Key[.="email_addr"]]/Value/text()`

Answer (score 1):

<sub><sup>A little late, but a bit more concise and complete...</sup></sub>

This XPath,

```
string(/OMRequest/Data/Item[Key="email_addr"]/Value)
```

will select the string value of the `Value` element associated with the given `Key` element.

Replace `string()` with `normalize-space()` and `Key` with `normalize-space(Key)` if you wish to return and compare space-normalized values rather than exact string values.